# In rich:fileUpload, if the user exceeds the maximum upload limit then how can we display a popup message to say so

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In rich:fileUpload, if the user exceeds the maximum upload limit then how can we display a popup message to say so.

```
<rich:fileUpload onclick="emptyFileCheck();" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}" id="upload" acceptedTypes="txt,xml,docx,pdf"
                                    ontyperejected="alert('Only txt,xml,docx and pdf files are accepted');" maxFilesQuantity="5" immediateUpload="true"
                                    onsizerejected="alert('Maximum file size allowed is 5MB.');"
                                    addControlLabel="Upload File">
```

Comment: I see an `onsizerejected="alert('Maximum file size allowed is 5MB.');"` So I interpret your question in that you do not want a basic browser alert but a real richfaces styleable popup?

Comment: Yes. Something like that. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: No idea, have not been using richfaces for over 10 years. Using PrimeFaces since then